# Remove .aspx from "Link To Document" in Umbraco 6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've used Umbraco 7 in many projects, but never Umbraco 6. The project is indeed a MVC project.

I ran into a similar problem earlier on this project regarding templates. When creating a template, it would create a .aspx page, rather than a view. I changed a configuration setting in /Config/umbracoSettings.config from **Webforms** to **Mvc**

```
<templates>
<!-- If you want to switch to Mvc then do NOT change useAspNetMasterPages to false -->
<!-- This (old!) setting is still used to control how macros are inserted into your pages -->
<useAspNetMasterPages>true</useAspNetMasterPages>

<!-- To switch the default rendering engine to MVC, change this value from WebForms to Mvc -->
<!-- Do not set useAspNetMasterPages to false, it is not relevant to MVC usage -->
<defaultRenderingEngine>Mvc</defaultRenderingEngine>
```

However, when creating content nodes, the default "Link To Document" on the properties page is indeed an `.aspx` extension. How can I remove this and just have the default view name, rather than the extension?

[image]

I know there are rewrites, but if it's an MVC project then why even have the extension there in the first place? I didn't have to do this in Umbraco 7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your web.config file, look for the setting "umbracoUseDirectoryUrls" in your AppSettings section. Set that to "true" and the .aspx part should not appear in the URLs and you'll get folder style URLs instead.

Comment: Appreciate it! - would of never found that.